# Usage of kivy layouts

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I am using kivy to build GUI for my program. In my kv file, I want the content of the first box layout to appear on the top right and the content of the second boxlayout to appear on the top left.
Below is the my kv file.
This is not behaving as expected. Please help

```
<AnchorLayout>:
    anchor_x: 'right'
    anchor_y: 'top'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        Button:
            text: 'Dashboard'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 80, 40
        Button:
            text: 'Task'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 80, 40
        Button:
            text: 'Work'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 80, 40

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        Label:
            text: 'Logo'
        Label:
            text: 'MU'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the poorly documented `AnchorLayout` only really works with just a single child. In your case, both of your `BoxLayouts` are positioned at the `right`, `top` of the `AnchorLayout`. However, both `BoxLayouts` have the default `size_hint` of `(1,1)`, so they both fill the `AnchorLayout`, and the `right` `top` anchor has no effect.

You can use `FloatLayout` instead of `AnchorLayout`, with `size_hint` and `pos_hint` to get your desired result:

```
<FloatLayout>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        pos_hint: {'right':1, 'top':1}
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.minimum_size

        Button:
            text: 'Dashboard'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 80, 40
        Button:
            text: 'Task'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 80, 40
        Button:
            text: 'Work'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 80, 40

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        pos_hint: {'x':0, 'top':1}
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.minimum_size

        Label:
            text: 'Logo'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 80, 40
        Label:
            text: 'MU'
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 80, 40
```